# Group By Not working - only displaying 1st entry

Tags: php, mysqli, group-by

I have over 40'000 entries and each is assigned to a "list_name"

I am basically trying to get just the list_name value echo'd out

```
$groupq = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM `products-full` GROUP BY `list_name`");
$groupr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($groupq);
do {
        echo $groupr['list_name'];
} while($groupr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($groupq));
```

however its only displaying 1 entry then no more ..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK8kf.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$groupq = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM `products-full` GROUP BY `list_name`");
 while($groupr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($groupq)){
  echo $groupr['list_name'];
}
```

Comment: Hi @ChrisYates, sorry i have given wrong variable name, try this one

Comment: yeah I noticed that and used correct one automatically shows only 1

Comment: Hi @ChrisYates, run this sql query in database, and check how many results are you getting

Comment: 1 strangely enough .. which is strange considering there are over 25 list_name values

Comment: Some thing was wrong in your database query, Please update your question with database screenshot, so we can help you

Comment: added image link

Comment: @ChrisYates, i can only see FGS BULK, so this was correct

Comment: you want list_name or style_desc?

Comment: list name but ive just found problem .. when I try to load up phpmyadmin it kept crashing so i emptied the db and uploaded just 20 products, these are all in the same list name ..
that might have been why it was only showing 1 ::facepalm::

Comment: Have accepted your answer anyway as that was down to my stupidity

Comment: @ChrisYates, Yes you wright list_name have only name, it was showing only one

Answer (score 0):

```
$database = "sample"   //replace your database name here
$conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","",$database);   // here username is root and password is null , change it according to yours
if($conn->connect_error)
{
     echo $conn->connect_error;
     die("sorry database connection failed");
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products-full GROUP BY list_name";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo $row['list_name'];   
    }
}
```

thats it

Comment: still same issue

Comment: what result did you get when you are executing this query `SELECT * FROM products-full GROUP BY list_name` in phpmyadmin SQL , can you please show me the snap shot of executing this query in phpmyadmin

Comment: can you check where the need of this query is correct  , visit https://www.guru99.com/group-by.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$groupq = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT list_name, count(*) FROM `products-full` GROUP BY 
`list_name`");
while($groupr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($groupq)) {
    echo $groupr['list_name'];
}
```